# How to show multi-line xml content with CRLF in WPF TextBlock?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, newline, textblock

I have an xml file like this:

```
<Items>
 <Item att1="val1" att2="val2" att3="
   att3 line 1 is long
   att3 line 2 is longer
   att3 line 3 is longest"/>
 ...
</Items>
```

The WPF TextBlock should show the value of att3 as follows:

```
   att3 line 1 is long
   att3 line 2 is longer
   att3 line 3 is longest
```

Instead I see the following:

```
att3 line 1 is long att3 line 2 is 
longer att3 line 3 is longest
```

**How do I get the WPF TextBlock to recognise CRLF characters which I can see when I open the file in NotePad++?**

**UPDATE:**
- Text is read from Xml by loading in a XDocument and reading the value into the TextBlock using Linq
- Yes, the CRLF characters are visible when seen in Notepad++
- TextBlock has TextWrapping enabled with "Wrap"
- Sample xml: http://sdrv.ms/1gGbeE3

Comment: How are you adding the text to the TextBlock control?

Comment: are you sure that you have CRLF char

Answer (score 0):

just  add the property  `TextWrapping="Wrap"`

```
<TextBlock  Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

I have tried this  in  code  behind  and works fine so you should be sure that you have \n in  your string

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string st = " att3 line 1 is long \n  att3 line 2 is longer \n   att3 line 3 is longest";
        textBlock.Text = st;  
    }
}
```